# Utilización de variables en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables

No estoy familiarizado con el uso de JS y tengo la siguiente duda:

¿Qué diferencia hay entre los dos siguientes ejemplos (en términos de uso de memoria)?

Ejemplo 1:

```
var a = 3;

a = 7;
```

Ejemplo 2:

```
var a = 6;

var a = 9;
```

¿En ambos casos solo se habría declarado una variable? Pregunto esto porque estoy planteando reutilizar variables para minimizar el uso de memoria.

Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el primer caso estás declarando y asignando valor a tu variable 'a' en la primera línea y reasignando otro valor en la segunda línea,

mientras que en el segundo estás declarando dos variables con el mismo nombre, lo cual debería generarte un error.

Siempre que puedas, declara tus variables al inicio de tu script o del bloque de código donde vaya a ser utilizada y no crees mas variables de las necesarias, a nivel de memoria será más óptimo, y para cualquiera que lea el código será mucho más comprensible.

Comment: No genera un error, la segunda declaración simplemente se ignora durante el *hoisting*

Answer (score 1):

El primer caso es redundante, ya que en la primera línea(`var a = 3;`) ya declaras el valor de `a` y en la segunda vuelves a asignar el mismo valor.

El segundo caso debería dar error porque estás creando dos variables con el mismo nombre, independientemente de su valor.

Comment: No falla, la segunda declaración sencillamente se ignora